# expressionengine: php error after install of nsm htaccess generator plugin: “The .htaccess path setting is a string. It should be an array.”

Tags: php, .htaccess, expressionengine

anyone using ee 2.1.3 and installed the "nsm htaccess generator"-plugin successfully?
i am facing the following problem after installation and enabling it:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: path

Filename: nsm_htaccess_generator/ext.nsm_htaccess_generator.php

Line Number: 568
The following errors were encountered

The .htaccess path setting is a string. It should be an array. 
If the setting has been manually set in the config.php (or config_bootstrap.php) update the value.
→ More information about this issue. ( http://ee-garage.com/nsm-htaccess-generator/support )
```

i haven't set the htaccess path manually. it's not set in the config.php and the config_bootstrap.php i haven't even found in my installation.

i am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the htaccess path in the plugin itself - (in EE2: Extensioins > NSM HT ACCESS GENERATOR > EXTENSION SETTINGS. Make sure you use a server path, not a web ( http:// ) path.